# Resetting the Forms Authentication in a web method

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I am using ASP.Net compact Version 3.5 S.P.I
I am running an app on a hand held scanner that calls web methods regularly.
I have  set up the Forms Authentication time out to 60 in the web config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms name="Auth" loginUrl="service1.asmx" protection="All" timeout="60" path="/" slidingExpiration="true" />

</authentication>

<p>
```

The time out counts down and the the user is brought back to the login when the authentication expires in the app. However, if I call a web Method , the timeout is not being reset at all. and If the login times out, the user is not brought back to the login screen. 
    
This is an example of one of the web methods I call
I would prefer not to add code for each web method to accomplish the time out being reset but will do If i have to.

```
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [ToolboxItem(false)]
public class STAWMS_WebService : WebService
    {
        private DataTable myCommonTable = new DataTable("Common");
        private DataTable myReturnData = new DataTable("ReturnData");
        private DataSet myReturnDataSet = new DataSet();

    private string SessionID = HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID;
    private string query;
    private int UserPK;
    private ArrayList myparams = new ArrayList();
    private DataSet myTempDataSet = new DataSet();
    private int ReturnIntegerTable;
    private int ReturnBooleanTable;
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public DataSet GetBuildUnitDetails(int StockInPK, int UserInPK)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                myparams.Clear();
                myparams.Add(new STASqlParameter("@StockInPK", StockInPK));
                myReturnData = STADatabase.SQLStoredProcedureSelect("GetStockInfo", myparams).Tables[0];
                myReturnData.TableName = "STA2";
                myReturnDataSet.Tables.Add(myReturnData.Copy());
                PopulateMyCommonTable(true, SessionID, true, UserInPK);
            }
            return myReturnDataSet;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            PopulateMyCommonTable(false, SessionID, false, UserInPK);
            return myReturnDataSet;
        }

    }
}
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an workaround you can proceed with the following:

If your `Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is `false` return `myReturnDataSet` as `null`. So you can check in the handheld if it is null just redirect to the login page.

```
    try
    {
        if (Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            ...
            return myReturnDataSet;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;//Here it will sign you is not authenticated.
        }            
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        ...
        return myReturnDataSet;
    }
```

Another thing, I don't know how things work in handheld version of the Framework but `loginUrl="service1.asmx"` should point to your login page.

Comment: Hi ya. I will have to write some code in .net to check if the user is still logged in because there are two different session ID between the application and the web service.